# How do I use a variable as table name in Django?

Tags: python, django-models

I'd like to do the following:

```
for table in table_list:
   'table'.samefield = newvalue
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the name of the application that it's in, then you can do

```
model = getattr(application_name.models, 'table')
model.somefield = newvalue
```

or just

```
getattr(application_name.models, 'table').somefield = newvalue
```

if you only want to access it once (although that doesn't really make any sense).

Comment: nice solution if the application name is known.